# Is there a way to process data inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

For example, if I have:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in lists">
  <th>{{x[0]}}</th>
  <th>{{x[1]}}</th>
  <th style="text-align:right">${{x[2]}}</th>
  <th>{{x[3]}}</th>
  <th>{{x[4]}}</th>
</tr>
```

I would like the `${{x[2]}}` part to be process and turned into format as `xx.00` with function similar to this:

```
x[2] = x[2].replace(new RegExp("^(\\d{" + (a.length%3?a.length%3:0) + "})(\\d{3})", "g"), "$1 $2").replace(/(\d{3})+?/gi, "$1 ").trim();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `number` filter to do it.

To format currency as `xx.00`, use  `{{ x[2] | number:2 }}`

Hope it can help.

Comment: Great, but what if I want to do something more complicated/based on if statements? Like if I want to replace 0 with "Visa" and replace 1 with "MasterCard"...

Comment: Use if/else condition: `{{ x ? 1 : 'Visa' : 'MasterCard' }}`. If `x` always return 0 or 1, you can use short condition `{{ x : 'Visa' : 'MasterCard' }}`, 1 is `true`, 0 is `false`

Comment: you can write your own filter to decorate the text with if statements

Comment: @WorkWe what happens when there are save five to ten values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter for this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp